# Which projective varieties cannot appear as an exceptional divisor of a blow-up of the projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, blow-ups

I am looking for examples of projective varieties (over $\mathbb{C}$) of dimension, say $n$ which cannot appear as an exceptional divisor of a blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ along some closed subscheme. Any idea/reference will be most welcome.

Comment: Is not the exceptional divisor always covered by rational curves (because it is the Proj of the normal sheaf)? This should exclude all the non-uniruled varieties, I think.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi By your argument that it is the Proj of a normal sheaf, can't we further say that the irreducible components of the exceptional divisor must be rational?

Comment: unirational, but not rational in general. If you blow-up a smooth curve $C$ of genus $g\geq 1$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, the exceptional divisor is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over $C$, that is not rational because it has irregularity $g$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Thanks. You could write your comments as the answer. This does answer my question to a large extent.

Comment: Ok, I wrote a short answer

Comment: btw, in my last comment "unirational" should be "uniruled".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exceptional divisor is the $\operatorname{Proj}$ of the normal sheaf, hence it is covered by rational curves. This excludes all the non-uniruled varieties.